# can someone help me translate this c programm to MIPS assembly?

Tags: c, assembly

```
int x=0;
int A[50,100];
main() {
j=bin_search (*A , item, Nelem){
temp=0;
temp=Nelem/2;
if(Nelem==1)
 return *x;
else (*x<item)
return bin_search(*x , item , temp)
else
return bin_search(*x+temp , item , temp)
```

Comment: 1. That's not a program, the braces don't even match. 2. @David Gelhar, how and why did you partially complete the code?

Comment: @Potatoswatter I just used the "format code block" button to preserve line breaks to make it easier to read. Doing that didn't help as much as I hoped :-)

Comment: +1 @Potatoswatter - not to mention the array declaration isn't C, the unary `*` being used on an integer, a bad if/else construct, and plenty of undeclared variables.

Comment: @David OK, SO's revision diff function is just being screwy again. It says you introduced new text.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, he did - 4 spaces at the beginning of each line of code.  The `<` in the middle of the code block was being interpreted as an HTML tag, so it just looks like code was added in the quick diff view, which shows the formatted display.  You can see what was going on by looking at the source for each revision.

Comment: @Potatoswatter well, technically I did -- 4 spaces at the start of each line...

Comment: @Carl Aah, so there, I actually learned something from this discussion :vD

Answer (score 3):

1. Get a C compiler that can output MIPS code - there is probably a version of gcc that will do.
2. `gcc -S` your source code.  Alternatively, compile into an object file and then use `objdump` to disassemble it.

Presto - code translated from C to assembly!

Comment: 1. I think that the following explains how to do this with -march http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.6/gcc/MIPS-Options.html

Comment: @Dana, yeah - but you still need a compiler with MIPS support built-in.  I guess most normal situations don't include such a thing (unless you're running on a MIPS machine, I guess).  A cross-compiler is likely to be necessary.

Comment: it's difficult for me now to get a c compiler. can anyone please find me the answer and post it here?thnx

Comment: @efi, I think with that statement you just guaranteed nobody is going to help you.  What's the problem with getting a compiler?

Comment: i'm not lazy but i don't know how to use it. this code was an exercise in a past exam and i'm trying to solve it by hand

Comment: @efi, if that code was on a past exam, it was impossible.  The code you've shown isn't valid C.

Comment: maybe i have make a mistake because i don't remember it exactly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're struggling you could use a cross-compiler set for the given CPU architecture to compile the C program and output the intermediate assembly instructions for your target architecture. GCC should be able to do this without too much trouble. If you're looking for a clean easy to read translation make sure to disable most or all optimizations.